# How to make media URLs Unique

Tags: urls, media, media-library

I am having an issue with my project that requires my media URLs to be unique. I have found that if a media item is uploaded, deleted, and reuploaded with the same name in the same month, then the URL for the media item is the same as the old item.

E.g.

1. I upload an item named "pic.jpeg" and the URL is "myserver/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/pic.jpeg"
2. I delete pic.jpeg from the Media Library
3. I upload a *different* item named "pic.jpeg" and the URL is "myserver/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/pic.jpeg"

I need the second uploaded item to have a different URL from the first, even though it was deleted.

Is there a way I can make media URLs truly unique, by changing the default URL from the "year/mo/name" format to something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly change the upload folder structure using an [`upload_dir` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_dir/) hook, but I think a more direct solution might be to append some other text to the end of the file name. I think an easy unique string could just be the current timestamp, and encoding it in hexadecimal would make it a little more compact.

I'm not too familiar with WordPress's media APIs, but it looks to me that the [`wp_handle_upload_prefilter` and/or `wp_handle_sideload_prefilter` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/action_prefilter/) (depending on how you are performing the upload) would be reasonable place to implement this functionality:

```php
function wpse408625_media_upload_append_ts( $file ) {
  $ext      = substr( $file['name'], strrpos( $file['name'], '.' ) );
  $filename = substr( $file['name'], 0, strlen( $file['name'] ) - strlen( $ext ) );

  $file[ 'name' ] = $filename . '-' . dechex( time() ) . $ext;

  return $file;
}

add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'wpse408625_media_upload_append_ts' );
add_filter( 'wp_handle_sideload_prefilter', 'wpse408625_media_upload_append_ts' );
```

The above should transform a filename such as `pic.jpeg` into one like `pic-62faeadd.jpeg`. As long as you don't manage to upload an image, delete it, then upload another with the same filename all within the span of one second, this should prevent future collisions!

Comment: This works great for uploading through the Media Library on the web, but I am uploading via the REST API. Do you know of a method for making this work in that situation?

Comment: @HannahEstes it looks like an upload through the REST API might trigger either `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` or `wp_handle_sideload_prefilter`, depending on the specifics of the request. I've added the other to the answer - does that seem to work for your use-case?

Comment: that worked! Thank you for your help